# How do i use libavfilter to deinterlace frames in my video player software

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I'm using libavformat/libavcodec/libswscale/libavutil/libavfilter (ffmpeg related libraries) to make a video player.

I'v gotten into issues with interlaced videos, it just pairs them incorrectly... It always draws the previous bottom frame with the current top frame. Which results in things I don't want. And i'v tried messing about with the variables around this, it just won't work. (I haven't found a player which would play the videos I have correctly, no you can't have them, i'm sorry)

I managed to find a way around this, by re-encoding the video with the following command:

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter:v yadif -vcodec mpeg4 out.avi

Now what i'd need is directions on how to do this with c++ code, inside my video player.

I haven't found any tutorials on the matter and the ffmpeg.c source code is just too alien to me.

A link to a tutorial would be fine, i just haven't found it..

Edit:

Also this example was worth checking out:

https://github.com/krieger-od/imgs2video/blob/master/imgs2video.c

It's by a gentleman named Andrey Utkin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [doc/examples/filtering.c](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.9/filtering_8c.html) from FFMPEG source.

Comment: excellent, I feel so stupid not finding that.. I'll accept this as an answer if I find all that i need in it. From first impressions, it seems to contain it all.